# Custom spring batch flow with custom processing and multiple input/output data types at reader, processor and writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a custom reader definition something like below:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class CustomItemReader implements ItemReader<String> {

  @Autowired
  BookingInfoRepository bookingInfoRepository;

  private List<String> bookingIds;


  @Override
  public String read() {
    if(Objects.isNull(bookingIds)){
      bookingIds = bookingInfoRepository.findDistinctId();
    }
    if (! bookingIds.isEmpty()) {
      return bookingIds.remove(0);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

So, I set the variable `bookingIds` with the ids returned from database.

And then, I have some custom processor that will talk to database and return objects:

```
@Component
@StepScope
@Slf4j
public class CorrectionProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, List<BookingInfo>> {


  @Autowired
  BookingInfoRepository bookingInfoRepository;

  @Override
  public List<BookingInfo> process(String bookingId) {
     
     List<BookingInfo> bookingInfoList = bookingInfoRepository.findById(bookingId);

     //do some processing, modify the objects in the list.

     return bookingInfoList;

  }


}
```

And then, I have a custom writer as shown below:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<List<BookingInfo>> {


  @Autowired
  BookingInfoRepository bookingInfoRepository;

  @Override
  public void write(Chunk<? extends List<BookingInfo>> chunk) throws Exception {
    for(List<BookingInfo> bookingInfo: chunk){
      bookingInfoRepository(bookingInfo);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my usecase ->

1. `Reader` expects to operate out of the master data which is a list of bookingIds.
2. Reader passes this individual `bookingId` to `processor` and **Processor** forms a list of custom objects to be returned to the writer. Note that the processor forms a `list` of objects and NOT a single object.
3. Writer need to take all the values in the list and save them to database.
4. Process continues until all `bookingIds` are processed.

I know that this may not be an ideal way of utilizing spring batch. `Reader` to `Processor` steps may look strange, but I need to stick with this implementation. I feel I'm doing something wrong in one or multiple steps mentioned above. I see that the `chunks` have data appended everytime. So, the same data is getting inserted multiple times. How can I write the newly added chunk to database instead of adding everything again and again? Is my other configs are correct?

Answer (score 2):

`@StepScope` annotation is wrong for your use case. It causes that the beans are being instantiated before every step execution and your local variable lose the content.

Use `@JobScope` for item reader instead. Remove the annotation from the other two beans as the default instantiation as singleton will be enough.

Please note: to enable job scope add @EnableBatchProcessing to one of the configuration classes.

Comment: Thanks! It helped to get rid of some erroneous behavior. 
But I'm still doing repeated writing in the writer. 
How can I write new chunks to database instead of writing the whole bunch of old records again and again?

Comment: Also, I removed `StepScope` from all other beans except reader. When I replace `StepScope` with `JobScope` in reader, then I get an error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
`

Comment: Can you try without any scope annotation?

Comment: when I remove the scope from reader, then `shipmentIds` list is not getting generated next time when the job is triggered. Because it has singleton scope.

Comment: Sure. That's why I suggested JobScope. But I'm curious if it fixed the other problem with multiple values?

Comment: No, I get the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope` when I add `JobScope` in reader and trigger the job. so, I'm unable to test the repeated values issue.

Comment: I mean after you removed the scope annotations. Is the other problem fixed?

Comment: after removing scope from reader, `bookingIds` list itself becomes empty and it stays there irrespective of triggering the job multiple times (because of singleton scope).

Comment: @StepScope is actually working with reader! 
For some reason,  it is getting into writer 3 times even though there are only two iterations to follow. Checking it.

Comment: I removed the scope from reader as you mentioned. I'm getting error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` referring to `bookingIds`. But I can confirm that writer is running exactly twice this time :) But, how to get rid of thsi error?

Comment: This error can only happen if you run the step in parallel. You never mentioned parallel processing. Your code is not thread safe because of the list held in the item reader.

Comment: Yes, I had a taskexecutor in the job config. I had to use a `ReentrantLock` and this problem went away! Sorry about the confusion :( .    Your inputs brought the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I see that the chunks have data appended everytime. So, the same data is getting inserted multiple times.

That is not correct. Chunks are cleared and garbage-collected after every transaction. Every new transaction should have a new chunk of data from the reader.

> How can I write the newly added chunk to database instead of adding everything again and again? Is my other configs are correct?

There is nothing to do more than what you shared. Spring Batch will do that with a chunk-oriented step.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! My issue was more about thread safety in parallel processing. So I fixed it with a locking mechanism for now.